# Time EditText Android output

Tags: android, android-edittext

I was wondering if anybody knew what output I would get if I did an EditText.getText() with an input type "time".

Would it be ##:##, just ####, or something completely different?

Thanks!

Comment: EditText.getText() always return CharacterSequence any kind of input ype...

Comment: Try it yourself. It is fairly simple